# How to develop a widget

Tags: android, widget

This is the first time I try to make a widget so be indulgent

I am trying to make a widget for android where I retrieve instantaneous values ​​from a cryptocurrency course, my code works perfectly in an activity, so I tried to reproduce it for the widget and this one does not work.

I probably did anything and also didn't understand how the widget itself works, but a little help would be welcome.

the result is that the textview does not display any results not even an error so I wonder if it is not up to the application to send the information but in this case how to make it automated

Thanks in advance

```
   static String serveur_url= "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCBUSD";
static String serveur_urlPrice="https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=BTCBUSD";

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, widgetText);

    RemoteViews nom = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.new_app_widget);
    nom.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,"test");

    RemoteViews pourcentage = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.new_app_widget);
    pourcentage.setTextViewText(R.id.pourcentage,"test");

    RemoteViews price = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.new_app_widget);
    price.setTextViewText(R.id.price,"test");

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, serveur_url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {


                            String symbol=response.substring(response.indexOf("symbol")+9,response.indexOf("priceChange")-3);
                            String pourcentage1=response.substring(response.indexOf("priceChangePercent")+21,response.indexOf("weightedAvgPrice")-3);

                            nom.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,symbol);
                            String replace =symbol.toString().replace("USDT","");

                            String replace1=replace.toString().replace("BUSD","");

                            nom.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1,replace1);

                            pourcentage.setTextViewText(R.id.pourcentage,pourcentage1 +"%");


                            requestQueue.stop();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text,"error");

                    error.printStackTrace();
                    requestQueue.stop();
                }
            });


            RequestQueue requestQueue1= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, serveur_urlPrice,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String responseprice) {




                            String price1=responseprice.substring(responseprice.indexOf("price")+8,responseprice.indexOf("}")-7);


                            price.setTextViewText(R.id.price,price1+"$");

                            requestQueue.stop();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text,"Error");
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    requestQueue1.stop();
                }
            });
            requestQueue1.add(stringRequest1);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here.

Regarding your specific concern, the problem is that you are updating the `RemoteViews` asynchronously, but you are not then calling `updateAppWidget()` again (or `partiallyUpdateAppWidget()`) to push the updated `RemoteViews` to the launcher process (by way of the OS). If you want your changes to the `RemoteViews` to take effect, you need to call `updateAppWidget()` or `partiallyUpdateAppWidget()` after making those changes.

Your next problem is that you are trying to do network I/O every second. Beyond being bad for the battery, it also may expensive for users, depending on how they are connecting to the Internet. Plus, the Binance owners may not be very happy with you.

A related problem is that you are trying to network I/O every second from what appears to be an `AppWidgetProvider`. Bear in mind that an `AppWidgetProvider` is a very short-lived object: it lives for one callback (e.g., `onUpdate()`), after which it is thrown away. More importantly, your process can be terminated at any time after that callback returns.

The solution to those latter two problems would be to carefully use `WorkManager` or `JobScheduler` to arrange to update your app widget periodically, or to use `android:updatePeriodMillis` in your app widget metadata XML. Those will also enforce longer minimum periods (15 minutes, rather than 1 second).